# Silverlight Memory Leak

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I really can't find a solution. I've checked all the standard memory leak issues i.e. PageActivity, DataTemplates etc. and it's nothing like that. I am using windbg and with !GCRoot I get:

> DOMAIN(097C9970):HANDLE(Pinned):52412f8:Root:  0ade4260(System.Object[])->
>     09deab28(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]])->
>     0a3a8708(System.Object[])->
>     0a42becc(System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)->
>     0a4267e4(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)->
>     0a40da84(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarDayButton)->
>     0a3cc8e8(System.Windows.Controls.Calendar)->
>     0a3ccd44(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler)->
>     0a3cc828(System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker)->
>     0a3cd594(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)->
>     0a3cd690(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)->
>     0a3cfcd0(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)->
>     0a3cfdcc(System.Windows.Controls.Border)->
>     0a3e11f0(System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter)->
>     0a3e00d0(System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)->
>     0a3dffd4(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)->
>     0a3e02d0(System.Windows.Controls.Border)->
>     0a3de464(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)->
>     0a3cc160(System.Windows.Controls.Expander)->
>     0a3cc0b8(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)->
>     0a3d4078(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)->
>     0a3d4174(System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)->
>     0a3d4f90(System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter)->
>     0a3d6398(System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter)->
>     0a3d4ff4(System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl)->
>     0a3d51e4(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)->
>     0a3cadd4(System.Windows.Controls.Activity)->
>     0a3caa4c(System.Windows.Controls.Grid)->
>     0a3ca310(EMSOLG.Registration.StudentPayDetails)

Is there any way I can find out with more detail where is the leak?

It happens when I change the selected value of the combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbPaymentMethod" Height="23" Background="LightYellow"  
 DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" 
 SelectedValue="{Binding intPaymentMethod,Mode=TwoWay}"
 SelectionChanged="cmbPaymentMethod_SelectionChanged" />
```

The Code behing for the event is:

```
PageActivity.IsActive = true;
tblAppForm thisApplication = (tblAppForm)this.DataContext;
thisApplication.curInvoiceAmount = 0;
RG.Amount = ;
thisApplication.curRecovery = 0;
txtInvoiceTotal.Text = "0.00";
```

When the control is unloaded I've tried setting the `DataContext = null;` as well as a host of other controls and variables that I thought might cause the leak

Comment: Just my 2 cents but have you looked into VS2010 SP1, its in Beta but its supposed to have a silverlight profiler?  (Its called Performance Wizard) http://rabeb.wordpress.com/2010/12/18/new-feature-for-silverlight-in-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1/

Comment: @Giddy:  I think thats only found in the Ultimate edition.

Comment: You must have some idea of the source code that goes along with this?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, will have a look into the performance profiler. In terms of the source code, i've got everything readily available but there is really nothing strange going on:

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How do you know you've got a memory leak? What objects are you leaking? How many are being leaked?

Comment: Memory leak... are you unsubscribing the event handlers? publisher.MyEvent -= publisher_MyEvent; See: http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/08/why-you-should-always-unscubscribe-event-handlers/

Comment: Ok, i.t.o how I know I've got a memory leak is if I do a !DumpHeap -type ControlName then it comes up with 3 instances and when I do a GCRoot it shows the code i've pasted above which shows that something is pinning the 09deab28(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]])-> object on all three forms, but I can't figure out what the object is?

Comment: I have unfortunately unsubscribed all the event handlers

Comment: Does performance profiler address memory profiling?  My impression was that it did not.

Comment: As far as I know It does not... I think I found the issue though, it looks like it's the calendar control/DatePicker, I will see if I can paste example code and explanation once I sort it out

Comment: I would give ANTS by Redgate a try it provides a more interactive means to interrogate the dump. Might give you a different perspective. There is a free/time limited version.

Comment: So it's definitely the datetimepicker in the silverlight 3 toolkit.It seems that the fix has been applied in v4 so I guess that might be the only solution short of getting a different control.

Comment: Have you tried to force the GC to run? GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Comment: Thanks svrist, unfortunately the object is pinned and GC will not be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we actually just bought the Telerik Tools for silverlight but if you really want to go through the trouble you can go look in the source code of the toolkit (Nov 2009, the newer versions should be fixed) and then just unsubscribe the eventhandlers after you've closed the calendar popup.